# Does Dart have something like `defaultdict` in Python?

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart, default

What I want to do is this below. 
Could you teach me how to do this if possible?

```
import 'package:my_package/data_object.dart';
Map<String, List<DataObject>> m = Map<int, List<DataObject>>(); // Create an empty map.
m['001'].add(DataObject(something: something)); // Can add DataObject without checking if '001' exists.
m['002'].add(DataObject(something: something));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `putIfAbsent` method on `Map` to create and insert e.g. an empty list to the map if it does not already exists: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Map/putIfAbsent.html

```
void main() {
  Map<String, List<int>> m = {};

  m.putIfAbsent('001', () => []).add(1);
  m.putIfAbsent('001', () => []).add(2);
  m.putIfAbsent('002', () => []).add(3);

  print(m); // {001: [1, 2], 002: [3]}
}
```

#### Alternative solution

If you are going to use this pattern a lot it can be easier to just implement your own Defaultdict class which is not that complicated since we just want it to behave like a Map:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class Defaultdict<K, V> extends MapBase<K, V> {
  final Map<K, V> _map = {};
  final V Function() _ifAbsent;

  Defaultdict(this._ifAbsent);

  @override
  V operator [](Object? key) => _map.putIfAbsent(key as K, _ifAbsent);

  @override
  void operator []=(K key, V value) => _map[key] = value;

  @override
  void clear() => _map.clear();

  @override
  Iterable<K> get keys => _map.keys;

  @override
  V? remove(Object? key) => _map.remove(key);
}

void main() {
  // Create a Defaultdict where we return a empty new list for unknown keys
  final m = Defaultdict<String, List<int>>(() => []);

  m['001'].add(1);
  m['001'].add(2);
  m['002'].add(3);

  print(m); // {001: [1, 2], 002: [3]}
}
```

Comment: Updated with alternative solution with defaultdict class example.

Comment: Updated alternative solution to null-safety.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `??=` when possible:

```dart
var m = <String, List<DataObject>>{};
(m['001'] ??= []).add(DataObject(something: something));
(m['002'] ??= []).add(DataObject(something: something));
```

Note that this isn't quite the same as using `putIfAbsent` since it will overwrite entries where the key exists but the value is `null`.  If you never store `null` in your `Map`, then use whichever you think is cleaner.