# "map.getOrDefault" equivalent in Dart

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, hashmap

I'm working on a friend suggestion algorithm for a flutter social media application. I'm still an amateur when it comes to Dart so I'm stuck on the following line of code:

```
class FriendSuggestionAlgorithm {
  User friendSuggestion(User user) {
    int max = -1;
    User suggestion;

    Map<User, int> map = new HashMap();

    for (User friend in user.friends) {
      for (User mutualFriend in friend.friends) {
        if (mutualFriend.id != user.id && !user.friends.contains(mutualFriend)) {
        map.putIfAbsent(mutualFriend, map.getOrDefault(mutual, 0) + 1);
      }
      }
    }

    for (MapEntry<User, int> mutualFriend in map.entries) {
      if (mutualFriend.value > max) {
        max = mutualFriend.value;
        suggestion = mutualFriend.key;
      }
    }
    return suggestion;
  }
}
```

`map.getOrDefault` is underlined (I know the method doesn't exist in Dart). Do you know what the equivalent is in Dart? (PS, I'm just translating Java code into Dart.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ATM doesn't exist, but you can do this way ``map.containsKey(key) ? map[key] : 0;``

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment @OMiShah! Question - using the way you've commented, how would I add it to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```dart
map.putIfAbsent(mutual, (map.containsKey(mutual) ? map[mutual] : 0) + 1)
```

Maybe take a look at this for more info: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions

Edit:

This code should work

```
class FriendSuggestionAlgorithm {
  User? friendSuggestion(User user) {
    int max = -1;
    User? suggestion;

    Map<User, int> map = {};

    for (User friend in user.friends) {
      for (User mutualFriend in friend.friends) {
        if (mutualFriend.id != user.id && !user.friends.contains(mutualFriend)) {
          map.putIfAbsent(mutualFriend, () => (map[mutualFriend] ?? 0) + 1);
        }
      }
    }

    for (MapEntry<User, int> mutualFriend in map.entries) {
      if (mutualFriend.value > max) {
        max = mutualFriend.value;
        suggestion = mutualFriend.key;
      }
    }
    return suggestion;
  }
}
```

Note that `suggestion` nullable because it could happen that suggestion is never assigned. And therefore `friendSuggestion(user)` can return null;

To come back to your question
the correct code is

```
map.putIfAbsent(mutualFriend, () => (map[mutualFriend] ?? 0) + 1);
```

My mistake on my original answer, the ifAbsent part of this is a function. In the function the value of `mutualFriend` is retrieved. If that is null use 0.

Comment: Hey @Er1 ! Thank you so much for your suggestion, unfortunately, I'm getting the following error: "`The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int Function()`"

Comment: @callMe_whatever maybe you could add what type `map` and `mututal` are to your question to make it more clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Er1 , I've just updated the code - I hope it's clearer now?

Comment: @callMe_whatever I edited my answer, hopefully it'll help.

Comment: Thank you soo much! It doesn’t throw any errors and works as expected!

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make sense. `map.putIfAbsent` will do work only if the key doesn't exist, so the hypothetical `map.getOrDefault` call with the same key would always return the default value anyway.  That is, your logic would be the equivalent of `map.putIfAbsent(mutual, () => 1)`, where nothing happens if the key already exists.

[`Map.putifAbsent`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/putIfAbsent.html) takes a *callback* as its argument to avoid evaluating it unless it's actually necessary.  I personally prefer using `??=` when the `Map` values are non-nullable.

I presume that you actually want to increment the existing value, if one exists.  If so, I'd replace the `map.putIfAbsent(...)` call with:

```dart
map[mutual] = (map[mutual] ?? 0) + 1;
```

Also see: [Does Dart have something like `defaultdict` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61198441/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this and give my feedback/accept it once I have tested it - thanks again!(:

Comment: Thank you so much! This also works as expected, but I already accepted the one below. Thank youu!

Comment: I’ve upvoted it so that people know it’s also correct!